# Add vCard data to contacts using Cordova Contacts plugin (or equivalent) with Cordova Barcode Scanner

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

If I were to scan a QR code that had vCard data using the [Cordova Barcode Scanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) plugin, would it be possible to parse and add this information to the contacts using the [Contacts Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts) or something equivalent? I looked in the GitHub repo of the Barcode Scanner and it looks like it does contain a vCard parser; however there is no information as to how to activate this.

Comment: ARe you going to use `ngCordova` and Ionic to do this or straight Cordova?

Comment: Preferably ngCordova and Ionic, but I am willing to use vanilla Cordova.

Comment: It matters because this becomes a bit easier with `ngCordova` and `Ionic` and your question should be tagged such.

Comment: So do you have a method or you just know that it can be done?

Comment: Looks like there's an issue out about it; and someone patched it to do that: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/14#issuecomment-118498493  Since `ngCordova` is just a wrapper around it; you could check the `ngCordova` source code to see if it also can take an `obj` and return only the scans for QR_Code.

Comment: But see, that would let me just restrict which type I scanned for.  How would I then take that data and convert it into a contact?

Comment: And do you have a solution for this?

Comment: I haven't used the QR code scanner; so I can only assume you'd read in the data, parse it; and then create a contact object out of it. I tried to improve the contact docs somewhat; I'll be able to do more as I work with the Contact plugin more; I have no immediate plans to use the barcode plugin, so you'll have to create a project and throw it on a device and do some debugging there. https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/pull/886